# Javascript - Callback inside callback? doesn't work for me with apparently no reason

Tags: javascript, function, api, google-chrome, callback

i'm trying to develop an extension for Google chrome, how does it work? well there is a web, everytime you go there it will redirect, however after some tries it will not redirect, what i need to do is that my extension automatically  enter that url until it stops redirecting.

I got this:

```
function update_tab(activeTab){
     chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
          activeTab = tabs[0];
     }
}

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({"url": "https://Example.com/SiteWanted"});
    wait(3000);
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    while(activeTab.url === "https://Example.com/SiteIDontWant"){
        chrome.tabs.update(activeTab.id,{url:"example.com/SiteWanted"});
        update_tab(activeTab);
        wait(3000); // i know this function is weird, but it is necessary for the code to work, and yes, i known that using functions to delay the code is not... right
    }
  }); 
});
```

I Have tried almost everything, changed var names, tried different methods like chrome.tabs.getCurrent, moved code (update_tab) inside main function and other stuff that i think that could help me, but there is no way i can solve this, what i have figured out is that the code inside update_tab won't run no matter what i do, and without that, url won't "update" inside the code, so the While loop will run forever and with that, the extension will enter the same url forever.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using while loop if condition met sure it will run forever.

```
    if(activeTab.url === "https://Example.com/SiteIDontWant"){
            chrome.tabs.update(activeTab.id,{url:"example.com/SiteWanted"});
            update_tab(activeTab);
            wait(3000); // i know this function is weird, but it is necessary for the code to work, and yes, i known that using functions to delay the code is not... right
        }
```

Comment: Because i need it to repeat the requests until the url matches with the one i want, using a simple conditional will run only one time. And btw, it won't run forever because that loop, i said that it was because update_tab.is not working. Anyway thanks for taking your time to reply :)

Comment: and if don't match it will continue forever. and i can see you are using onClicked means you want to things happened when user click then should try some other logic otherwise it will just keep going..

Comment: I know, i want that loop to go forever until i get the url i want, i don't have any problem with that. and yup, it uses onClicked because i need it to execute when user press the extension button, that's how it's supposed to work